# References to generic type should be parameterized. A constructor or a type argument related warning

Tags: java, generics

I'm creating a LinkedList class and a LinkedListNode and I want them to be generic so that I can choose type arguments later depending on the situation.
So I created these two classes:

DoublyLinkedList class:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {

    // sentinel before first item
    private NodeDoublyLinked<T> head;
    // sentinel after last item
    private NodeDoublyLinked<T> tail;
    //number of elements
    private int size;

    // getter and setter methods here

    //add new node to the linked List
    public void addNode(T data){

        NodeDoublyLinked<T> prev = tail.getPrev();
        NodeDoublyLinked<T> node = new NodeDoublyLinked(data, prev, tail);
        tail.setPrev(node);
        size++;

    }
}
```

and the NodeDoublyLinked class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class NodeDoublyLinked<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private T data;
    private NodeDoublyLinked<T> prev;
    private NodeDoublyLinked<T> next;

    public NodeDoublyLinked(T value, NodeDoublyLinked<T> previousN, NodeDoublyLinked<T> nextN) {
        this.data = value;
        this.prev = previousN;
        this.next = nextN;
    }

    // getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new NodeDoublyLinkedIterator();
    }

    private class NodeDoublyLinkedIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        // the current node returned by next()
        NodeDoublyLinked<T> current = prev.next;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            // code here

        }

        public void remove(){
            // code here

        }

    }

}
```

In the method addNode in DoublyLinkedList class, at this line:

```
NodeDoublyLinked<T> node = new NodeDoublyLinked(data, prev, tail);
```

I get a warning:

> NodeDoublyLinked is a raw type. References to generic type
>   NodeDoublyLinked should be parameterized

I checked the [documentation of generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) so I understand that I should assign a type parameter at the right side but it's not correct either. Should I replace the type parameter with a type argument like Integer for example? Is there something wrong with the constructor of NodeDoublyLinked?

Comment: *"...so I understand that I should assign a type parameter at the right side but it's not correct either..."* What do you mean by "it's not correct either"? What did you do? (You haven't shown it.)

Comment: `code` NodeDoublyLinked<T> node = new NodeDoublyLinked<T>(data, prev, tail); `code` => the compiler returns an error.

Comment: What error do you get when you add `<T>` to constructor's invocation?

Comment: There is no contructor like the one I invoked. When I add a constuctor like it, I get an error in the constructor: previousN cannot be resolved to a variable. Also if I use just the brackets <> in invokation I get an error.

Comment: Using `<T>` in constructor invocation fixes the problem: [demo](http://ideone.com/pmBrqH).

Comment: I just discovered what was wrong.. I was using an int as an argument.. I don't know how I missed it. Thank you.